# Do method names always have to be verb?

Tags: java, methods

I am new to java programming, and I am currently working on a command reading program (basically the user types in a command and my program evaluates what to do and does it). I have a separate class that contains all my commands, but they're stored as methods and aren't always using verbs as names. I understand that it is customary have methods stored as verbs. Am I using methods wrong and is there a better way to store my commands? Separate class for each command? Example of calling one of my methods:

```
else if (command[0].equals("math")) Commands.math();
```

Comment: According to the [Java documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) *Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized*. Since methods represent, in fact, actions that deal with the behavior of the class where they're defined/implemented, you should use verbs. For instance, you should understand what your `math` command does, translate it to an action and, from there, to the verb that concretizes that action.

Comment: The Java API contains many methods whose names are not verbs: Math.sin, LocalDate.of, Collections.singleton(). Generally, the guideline is that if the purpose of the method is to _do_ something, it should be a verb; and if its purpose is to _return_ a value, it should be a noun or an adjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Do method names always have to be verb?

As far as the Java language (i.e. the Java compiler) is concerned, no.  The language spec only requires you to follow some rules about what characters are used, and about contextual uniqueness.

Typical Java Style Guides don't *require* method names to be verbs either.  But they typically *recommend* this.  (Note that this is not something that automated style checkers check, because of the difficulty of *reliably* distinguishing nouns and verbs.)

> I understand that it is customary have methods stored as verbs.

That is a better characterization.

This actually comes out of Object Oriented Design.  A class in the design maps to a Java class, and the Java methods represent actions on the instances on the design classes.  It is "natural" (and customary) to use noun-like identifiers for classes, and verb-like identifiers for methods.

But it is NOT a requirement.

---

In your example, you could simply address the dilemma by using "doMath" as the method name.  That is a verb phrase.  (The "do xyz" is a commonly used convention, albeit that it doesn't "read" very well.)

However, it seems like you could, and possibly should avoid hard-wiring the command names into the method names.   Take a look at the "Command" design pattern: [http://www.fluffycat.com/Java-Design-Patterns/Command/ <sup>(archived)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20190917150902/http://www.fluffycat.com/Java-Design-Patterns/Command/).

Design patterns are something you will need to learn in the long run, but they are possibly too much for a beginner programmer to digest.

Answer (score 1):

1. Must methods be verbs? No. As long as the compiler is concerned, it doesn't matter.
2. Should they be verbs? As a convention that will make programs easier to understand: Clearly yes.

Variables represent objects and data, so you should normally use a noun. Methods represent actions, so you should normally use a verb. There are exceptions, of course but that is the normal rule. Ideally the name of a variable or method should be enough to identify it's function in the class.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more object oriented you may consider using Abstract Class Command and separe classes extending it as classes

Comment: I should make the class containing the main method abstract?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should put all the methods in the same class, but other than that, you are using methods correctly.

I'm a Java programmer, and I've never heard of the verb custom. However, If you  want to follow it, some suggestions for method names are `doMath()` or `calculateMath()` or something similar.

Also, you should **NOT** be splitting up methods by class. Generally, you should only use multiple classes if you are planning to instantiate objects of the different classes. Putting each method in a separate class is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: I was actually thinking of splitting them up by class because the math command will have different functions (basic operations, solving equations), but I won't do that if I can put methods inside methods...

Comment: you can put multiple methods in each class. I wouldn't recommend putting all of the code in one method, but I would strongly suggest putting all the code in one class.